# how to set environment variable in powershell ? -WINDOWS

Tags: node.js, powershell, express

I think the question is pretty clear.
How can i set environment variable in powershell ?
I searched a lot in google and stackoverflow but nothing worked for me.

I tried

```
$env:NODE_ENV='production'
$SET NODE_ENV='production'
SET NODE_ENV='production'
SET NODE_ENV=production
```

none of above codes worked for me

Comment: Assigning it as you would a variable is working for me:

>$env:SOTEST = 'Test'
>$env:SOTEST
Test

Comment: `$env:NODE_ENV='production'` works, but the resulting environment variable only lives as long as the _current session_ (process). See the linked duplicate for details, including for how to define _persistent_ environment variables (on Windows).